# Cucumber / JUnit - How to proceed when test failed inside a loop?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber

Good evening,

I investigated hours to find a solution for the following problem:
I'm using Eclipse, Cucumber, JUnit & Maven. 
How is it possible to get a single test step will be marked as failed. It has been possible for me to fail the whole Scenario with try-catch and Assert.fail(), but not one case inside a loop.

Attached a part of my code:

Scenario:
Then Execute Login on page
|455xxxxxx10|4xx0|
|455xxxxxx10|4xx0|
|455xxxxxx10|4xx0|
|455xxxxxx10|4xx0|
|455xxxxxx10|4xx0|

It's quite possible that one number is wrong and then the whole scenario will be failed? It would be great to mark this single case as error and execute the loop again.

````
        List<String> credentials = dataTable.asList(String.class);
        driver.get("URL");
        sessionID = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("CookieName").toString();

        for (int a=0, b=1; a<credentials.size() & b<=credentials.size(); a+=2, b+=2)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("LOGIN")).click();
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/span")));```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you should use a scenario outline.

```
Scenario Outline: Then Execute Login on Page
Given: "<User>" logs into the page
|User        |
|455xxxxxxxxx|
|4xx0        |
|4xx0        |
```

This will run every the test scenario for whatever user (Or whatever your using to login. I guessed it was a user) as a separate test. So if one of the scenarios fails. You will be able to see which one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use scenario outline. Try the following:

```
Feature: Login Feature - Verify if user is able to Login into the site.

Scenario Outline: Login as a authenticated user
 Given user is on homepage
 When user navigates to Login Page
 Then I enter Username as "<username>" and Password as "<password>"

Examples:
|username  |password|
|455xxxxx10|4xx0    |
|455xxxxx10|4xx0    |
```

P.S.: Pay attention to the key words. You could not write

```
 Feature: Login Feature
Verify if user is able to Login into the site
```

because there is not key word before "Verify if user...."